# Use of environment variable for username in a shortcut

Tags: shortcut

I can run a .bat file with a path such as
"C:\Users\Stan\Desktop\PosnPushAlert.lnk"

But if I try to use
"C:\Users%USERNAME%\Desktop\PosnPushAlert.lnk"

it fails.

If I run the .bat file directly instead of from a shortcut, then using the environment variable works.
I'm using the shortcut to keep the window hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the \ in "C:\Users%USERNAME%\Desktop\PosnPushAlert.lnk"

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to use and environment variable in Easylanguage which does not recognize environment variables.